# How to update "Security update" on Android Studio AVD

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have to enroll a virtual android device on Microsoft Intune to test application deployment.

So I have installed the latest version of Android Studio on Windows 10.
Then I have created an AVD based on Pixel 4 model with Google Play services.

I have connected my Google account, downloaded and installed the Intune Company Portal.

But the compliance check aborted due to an outdated Security Update version.
When I check on settings I realized that the version is September 2020.
When I try to check new version the answer is "Up to date".

Is it possible to update the device security update to the last one ?

If yes, how can I do this ?

Kind regards,